# XSL on PDF format

Tags: php, xsl-fo

```
<fo:block>

It has been recommended that _______________<fo:inline text-decoration="underline"><xsl:value-of select="/root/demo/student_name"/></fo:inline> will receive the following services/placement:      

</fo:block>
```

Hey guys.. Im working on a project and encountered this little problem.. whenever "student_name" in "" has a value, it displays:

> Output: It has been recommended that ***_*__**_John DOE will receive the
>   following services/placement.

How can I come up with a solution that whenever "student_name" is not
set, it will just display "It has been recommended that ***_*___**
will receive the following services/placement."? help me.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [xsl choose](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_choose.asp)

```
<fo:block>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="/root/demo/student_name != ''">
     <xsl:value-of select="/root/demo/student_name"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <fo:inline text-decoration="underline">   </fo:inline> 
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
will receive the following services/placement: 
</fo:block>
```

It is not working example but I hope it gives you the idea where to look at.

And before all, take a look at the documentation it is not more then 15-20 min to  read it all
[W3Schools XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an xsl:if statement, it allows you to test if the node is there much like you would while using xsl:choose, however you can probably achieve the result you want in one line like this...

```
<fo:block>

It has been recommended that _______________<xsl:if test="/root/demo/student_name"><fo:inline text-decoration="underline"><xsl:value-of select="/root/demo/student_name"/></fo:inline></xsl:if> will receive the following services/placement:      

</fo:block>
```

This checks to see if the student_name node is THERE, if you want to check to see if it is empty or not you could use the != comparator, but it doesn't seem necessary in this case since if it is blank if you arent changing spacing or placement in any major way it shouldn't hurt anything.